# Versioning Lookup Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm creating some enterprise master lookup tables in SQL Server 2008r2.  I'm required to keep a table specific to a domain.  For example Gender would be a table and City could be another table.  In each table I keep Start and End dates to keep history.

Now I'm being asked to version these so you would know something like V1 had these codes and V2 had these updated codes.  Thinking about one lookup table is pretty straight forward.  Using Gender for example you could have a Gender table, a GenderVersion table and a GenderToGenderVersion linking table.  This would require 2 extra tables per lookup.  With just a few tables that is manageable but I’m hoping to get an idea for a better way to do this with many lookup tables

A few requirements.

- As stated, lookup tables must be domain specific. I cannot combine
  them.
- Junior level programmers must be able to build a select
  statement to find all the look values based on a specific version.

Any ideas?  I hate the idea of having 3x the required tables.

**[Edit]
Additional Details**

We need to be able to determine exactly what codes were in a particular version.
We need codes that are not edited or removed from a previous version to be part of the next version.
We do maintain start and end dates in the codes.  The version labels are in addition to the start and end dates.

Here is a sample model using Race.  This is with the

**RaceVersion table**

- RaceVersionID
- VersionLabel
- StartDate
- EndDate

**RaceToRaceVersion**

- RaceID
- RaceVersionID

**Race table**

- RaceID (used just for the master code DB)
- RaceCode (used for all other systems that use these codes)
- RaceDescription
- StartDate
- EndDate

Both the code and the version get date searchable effective dates. 
You can find an version and then relate to the code

Whenever there is a change to the codes, in this case Race, you can add a new version then find all the rows that are currently effective and populate the linking table.

This works well for a few sets of codes.  I'm hoping for functionality like this that scales better.

Comment: This is a common situation in data warehousing; you might want to look into [slowly changing dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) for different approaches to handling these versions.

Comment: I have several ideas, but the approach really depends on exactly *why* you need to do this. Here, if I needed to know which genders were in version 1, I'd check out the table "Gender" tagged "v1.0" from version control.

Comment: Pondlife - My "Code" tables are type two SCD's. (See the edits I made on my post for example) That was the initial approach I took and should normally be all that is needed.  However, a committee decided that they absolutely needed a Version Label on top of the date specific type 2 SCD.

Comment: It sounds like you have to make a trade-off between 'easy' (duplicate the entire table - or at least the IDs - every time a new version is released), or 'smart' (store changes only and reconstruct full versions dynamically). It's impossible to say which is better in your situation because we don't know all the details of your requirements, but personally I would go with easy and use some extra disk space, it's cheaper than your time. A few simple scripts should be enough to 'archive' a complete version when you need to. But again, I don't know precisely what your priorities are.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid multiple tables if you added a `version` column to each lookup table. Each time a new version of the data is entered, increment the version. When selecting data from the lookup, you'll always have to specify the correct version.

```
id | version | name
---------------------------------
 1 |       1 | Lookup Name for V1
 1 |       2 | Lookup Name for V2

SELECT name 
FROM lookup
WHERE id = 1
    AND version = 2
```

If you want to easily select the latest version, you'll need to create a view:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM lookup lu
WHERE version = (
    SELECT MAX(version)
    FROM lookup lu2
    WHERE lu.id = lu2.id
)
```

However, this view would have a performance cost that may outweigh the cost of maintaining more verbose select statements that include the version every time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  However, this approach won't work for me.  Let's say I have 5 lines of data that are all V1.  Then a new line is added to make 6 total lines that are now considered V2.  V2 is made up off all the new edits and any maintained previous lines.  We have a need to determine what V1 and V2 is.  So this method would require adding new rows for everything that is maintained.  That is not something we want to do.

Comment: @user2356282, so you're saying that you are treating versions as a snapshot of all the lookup data, not just a single row? Or more specifically, what is the full scope of the version as you envision it? Does a single version relate only to the row, only to the particular lookup table, or to the entire set of lookup tables in the database?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that popped into my mind is a versionId field in all these tables and a version table describing what each versionId means.  Same number of tables, more records in each.

**Edit starts here**

The second thing that popped into my head was to also add an ApplicationId and table.  That way not all applications have to be on the same version.